# Can i use unmanaged DLL without its pdb file? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, project, pdb-files

i have a project in c# that use a unmanaged [dll](/questions/tagged/dll) from another project, i have try to import that [dll](/questions/tagged/dll) file, but i cannot use that dll file because Visual Studio cannot find its .pdb file, me neither.

i have tried to dll import

```
[DllImport("unmanaged.dll", EntryPoint= "Analyse", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern unsafe long* Analyse(byte[] bImgData, uint nLength, ushort nWidth, ushort nHeigth, uint nMaxCodeCount, short nAnalyseLevel);
```

but the method just doesnt return any value. 
and in Output List there are:

> 'CCan.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Masbro\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CCan\CCan\bin\x86\Debug\unmanaged.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

can i use unmanaged DLL without its pdb file?or can i generate its .pdb file?

Comment: A pdb is only used for debugging.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the dll, pdb is used fro debugging purposes only.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the PDB. However, you do need to know the entry point and function signature of the API you're calling in the DLL; Visual Studio won't figure those out for you. However, if your DLL exports its function names, you can find them using various tools. Some examples here, on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/31d242h4(v=vs.100).aspx

For example, let's say your library, `unmanaged.dll`, has the following API:

```
void* DoStuff (DWORD number, LPWSTR str, PDWORD outval);
```

To call that from C# code, you would need to define the following `extern` function in in one of your classes:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices

[DllImport("unmanaged.dll", CharSet=Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr DoStuff (UInt32 number, String str, out UInt32 outval);
```

The visibility modifier (public) isn't important, except that you need to be able to see the function from wherever you call it. The `DllImport` attribute is defined in `System.Runtime.InteropServices`, hence the `using` statement.

DllImport requires the first value, the string giving the DLL name, but it also has a ton of other parameters which are sometimes helpful or even required (such as `CharSet`). In particular, if your unmanaged library doesn't export names (or you want to use a different name in C# than the exported unmanaged name) then you need to specify the `EntryPoint` field of the DllImport attribute. An example of accessing a function without an exported name if you know the function's ordinal:

```
[DllImport("unmanaged.dll", CharSet=Unicode, EntryPoint="#1")]
public static extern IntPtr DoStuff (UInt32 number, String str, out UInt32 outval);
```

Take a look at [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) for more info.

Comment: i've tried that but the method just doesnt return any value

Comment: What is the expected return type? You might need to set the `PreserveSignature` field on the DllImport attribute, if the p/invoke code thinks its an error indicator...